# Django ordering by random when using annotate

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-queryset

If I order my queryset randomly and print it out, like this:-

```
[p for p in Player.objects.order_by('?')]
```

it works as you'd expect. The players appear in a random order.

And if I order them by the number of games they've played, like this:-

```
[p for p in Player.objects.annotate('games').order_by('games__count')]
```

it also works as you'd expect. The players appear in order of the number of games they've played.

But I want to randomise the players that have played the same number of games. So I do this:-

```
[p for p in Player.objects.annotate('games').order_by('games__count', '?')]
```

and it completely breaks it. The query takes a second or two to run, I get the same player over and over, and they're all over the place in terms of order.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: what if, in model's `Meta`, you set `ordering` to games count, and then call `order_by` only with `'?'`?

Comment: I don't think you can do that - games is a related field, so I can't put it in the ordering.